# Jobs/Files stuck in Training for more than 24h

Tags: microsoft-translator

I have a couple of files in 2 different projects that are "Training" for more than 24h now in the new Custom Translator (not Translator Hub). Each is only 26,000 sentences approximately, so it doesn't really justify the wait. I have no other status screens or resources to search, so any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were experiencing some issues related to training last week that were causing 
model training times to run longer than they should. We have since fixed the problem and I hope that your job has completed at this time.

Comment: I'm getting this now: Dataprocessingfailed although the datasource is a straightforward TMX file in english/spanish. Why does that error show up?

Comment: How big are the tmx files?  There is currently a limit of 100k sentences on individual files.  This will be removed when we deploy the next build.  Is this possibly your problem?

Comment: Yes, definitely. I have 160k in one and maybe 230k in another one. When is the next deploy? And thanks for the information!

Comment: I can't say when it will happen, but we are hoping for the end of next week.

Comment: Thanks, I will try again in 10 days or so.